# Performance when using distinct and row_number pagination

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance, query-performance

I have a SQL something like this:

```
SELECT A,B,C,FUN(A) AS A FROM someTable
```

The problem is `FUN()` is a function which quite slow, so if there are a lot of records in `someTable`, there will be a big performance issue.

If we using a pagination, we can resolve this issue, we do the pagination like this:

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT A,B,C,FUN(A), Row_number()OVER( ORDER BY B ASC) AS rownum FROM someTable
)T WHERE T.rownum >=1 AND T.rownum<20
```

In this script, the `FUN()` will only execute 20 times so the performance is OK.
But we need use alias to order by, so we can't write rownum inline, have to move to sub query or CTE, we chose CTE and it looks like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT A,B AS alias,C,FUN(A) FROM someTable
)
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT *,Row_number()OVER( ORDER BY alias ASC) AS rownum FROM CTE
)T WHERE T.rownum >=1 AND T.rownum<20
```

So far we are going fine, we get pagination to solve performance issue, we solve the alias order problem, but somehow we need to add `DISTINCT` to the query:

```
 ;WITH CTE AS (
       SELECT DISTINCT A,B AS alias,C,FUN(A) FROM someTable
    )
    SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT *,Row_number()OVER( ORDER BY alias ASC) AS rownum FROM CTE
    )T WHERE T.rownum >=1 AND T.rownum<20
```

After this, the optimize of this SQL seems gone, the `FUN()` will execute many times as much as the records count in `someTable`, we get the performance issue again.

Basically we are blocked at here, is there any suggestions?

Comment: what is `FUN()` ?

Comment: Is `FUN` deterministic? (meaning will it return the same value each time it gets the same input)

Comment: @Zohar Peled, nope, it's dynamic, in fact it might be a sub query, so it's hard to cache a full result or a map for it, we tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in order to get distinct values, the database engine must run the `fun(a)` function on all the records being selected.

If you do the `fun(a)` only in the final select, the `distinct` should not effect it, so it should run only on the final 20 records.

I've changed the derived table you've used to another cte (but that's a personal preference - seems to me more tidy not to mix derived tables and ctes):

```
;WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT A,B AS alias,C
    FROM someTable
), 
CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY alias) As RowNum
    FROM CTE1
)

SELECT *, FUN(A)
FROM CTE2
WHERE RowNum >= 1 
AND RowNum < 20
```

Please note that since the `fun` function is not deterministic you might get results that are different from your original query - so before adapting this solution compare the results first.

Comment: yeah, your note is my concern, in this way the `FUN(A)` field will not consider by `DISTINCT`, so the result will be different.

Comment: Well, perhaps a better idea would be to improve the `FUN` performance - but that should be a topic for a different question.

Comment: I think u r right, as long as the DB has to execute the function on all records, we can't do anything. I will try to replace the function field with some other fields combination to achieve same goal of distinct, then run function after pagination, thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to help :-)